# Where does the definition files of Core in ruby?

Tags: ruby

After intalling `Ruby`, I can find the definition files of Standard Library in `C:\Ruby22-x64\lib\ruby\2.2.0` folder.

As Doc shows (e. g. for an [`Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html),) the definition files of `Core` maybe in files with the suffix `c`, like `array.c`.

Where can I find the definition of `Core`?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the implementation you are using. In [YARV](http://www.atdot.net/yarv/), the core library's implementation files (in [c](/questions/tagged/c)) reside in the [top-level directory of the source tree](https://github.com/ruby/ruby). In [Rubinius](http://rubinius.com/), the core library is largely implemented in the [`core` subdirectory](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/tree/master/core) of the source tree (in [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby)), but some smaller parts are implemented as builtins of the virtual machine (in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)), in the [`machine/builtin` subdirectory](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/tree/master/machine/builtin) of the source tree. In [JRuby](http://JRuby.Org/), the core library's implementation resides in the [`core/src/main/java/org/jruby`](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/tree/master/core/src/main/java/org/jruby) ([java](/questions/tagged/java)) and [`core/src/main/ruby/jruby`](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/tree/master/core/src/main/ruby/jruby) ([ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby)) subdirectories. In [IronRuby](http://ironruby.net/), it sits in the `Src/Ruby/Builtins` subdirectory ([c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)). In [Topaz](http://topazruby.com/), the subdirectories [`topaz/objects`](https://github.com/topazproject/topaz/tree/master/topaz/objects) and [`topaz/modules`](https://github.com/topazproject/topaz/tree/master/topaz/modules) are what you are looking for (written in [rpython](/questions/tagged/rpython)). In [Opal](http://opalrb.org/), you'll want to look at the [`opal/corelib`](https://github.com/opal/opal/tree/master/opal/corelib) subdirectory, mostly (in [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby)). In [MRuby](https://mruby.org/), the core library lives in [`mrblib`](https://github.com/mruby/mruby/tree/master/mrblib/) (part [c](/questions/tagged/c), part [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby)). In [MagLev](http://maglev.github.io/), parts are implemented in [smalltalk](/questions/tagged/smalltalk) in [`src/smalltalk/ruby`](https://github.com/MagLev/maglev/tree/master/src/smalltalk/ruby) and parts in [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) in [`src/kernel`](https://github.com/MagLev/maglev/tree/master/src/kernel)

Comment: Can I think this Ruby is implemented by C++ here?  
I find some files with the suffix h in include folder.